# Not able to set Publisher in appxmanifest file for windows app

Tags: appxmanifest

Am generating a windows app using Visual Studio. Have set the Identity name ,publisher name and publisher ID in package.windows.appxmanfiest , package.phone.appxmanifest and package.phone.appxmanifest files.

However when i build the solution , i can see that in all the Release folders ( for windows ARM , x86 and x64) , the appxmanifest file has the publisher as CN=Apache cordova team , instead of my defined value.

Am I missing anything here? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the cause of this issue.
In visual studio if you build a cordova application, it creates a pfx file and signs the package with that which has the publisher name as APACHE CORDOVA TEAM.

Specifying the publisher name in config.xml or any other manifest file or build.json gets ignored.
To fix this issue , had created a pfx file with the required publisher name and replaced it with the default cordova.pfx file in the solution.
This fixed the issue.

Comment: I'm having this issue and not sure how you did this.  (create a pfx file with required publisher name, and replace with the default cordova.pfx file).  I'm upgrading an existing W8.1 app with a new Windows 10 app and associate the existing app in Visual Studio 2017, so all of that is supposed to be done for you by Visual Studio.  But it's not working.